# Is it possible to give a existing CSS to some editor and it will generate LESS type dynamic CSS where we have variables expressions e.t.c

Tags: less

I find LESS framework a very nice step forward in doing CSS programitcally.
I wanted to check what could be the less tyle dynamic css for some existing css.
So wanted to check if it is possible that we can genrate dynamic css from an existing CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything that will do it for you, and I'm not sure how useful that would be anyway. However, note that valid CSS is also valid LESS and valid SCSS (if you want to go the Sass way) so you can just start with that and add bits of dynamism incrementally.

Kind of like how valid JavaScript is also valid TypeScript.

Comment: IT will help me in pitfall of existing CSS in some project.
Also I can learn a lot of just visualizing what can be possible in the existing CSS by expressing it in LESS way e.t.c.